# Handling exceptions in android intents

Tags: android, mobile, android-intent

I'm a totally Android newbie who's learing about intents.  I'm working on a small application to stream youtube videos.  My question is do I have to do anything especial when invoking an intent?  what happens when the intent fails?  I'm I responsible for handling exceptions?  Do I have to do register the intent so I can invoke it?  Thanks

Comment: You need to register the intent... But you don't have handle Exceptions since it does't throw any... And when an Intent fails you don't get the result thats it..

Comment: So are you saying that the OS prevents intents from throwing exceptions or is it a convention?

Answer (score 0):

when you are invoking an intent, it means you will deal with any of the provided components like Activity, Receiver, service ect . so the case where operation inside this component throws some exception, for example an activity throws a NPE , that should be handlelled withing that component itself or within activity for this example . even if you will handle it at the time of invocation , despite being unusual and not recommended approach , like this :

try
{
startActivity( . .);
}
catch 
{
}
this will not going to handle exception, thrown from inside activity code .

so conclusion is that neither android OS nor you should handle it at the time of invocation, but handle them at specific places where possible that any exception can accrue .